# Reinforced.Typings fails with MSB6006 when net5.0-windows specified

Tags: reinforced-typings

I use `Reinforced.Typings` and target my project as `net5.0-windows`.
Build fails with the below error because such a moniker is not targeted: the `tools` folder contains `net5.0` among others, but not `net5.0-windows`.

```
C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\reinforced.typings\1.6.1\build\Reinforced.Typings.targets(61,3): error MSB6006: "" exited with code 1. 

C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe "C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\reinforced.typings\1.6.1\tools\net5.0-windows\rtcli.dll" profile "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp813E.tmp" 
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
```

Would it be possible to target this framework too @pavel-b-novikov?

Any other ideas on how to force MSBuild to `Reinforced.Typings` to "redirect" from `net5.0-windows` to `net5.0`?

Or maybe that's something that can be configured on the MSBuild level?

Obviously, the obvious solution would be if I change my target to `net5.0`, but it's not possible due to other dependencies at the moment, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to specify `RtForceTargetFramework` as [per documentation](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/wiki/Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml#-rtforcetargetframework-string):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RtForceTargetFramework>net5.0</RtForceTargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```